# How can I get the facebook id of a user on my page with the like button?

Tags: facebook, api, twitter, google-plus

*My original intention is to know whether web developer can use the like button to track me.  But I guess, it is not an appropriate question here, hence have reversed the view point.*

Suppose I include the facebook like button, google +1 button and the tweet this button.  Can I track the user ids of each of these services in case the user has already logged into those services?  (But he does not press any of those buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you shouldn't be allowed to know a user's id if the user doesn't allow you to, somehow (by clicking "Like" or "Logging with FB" button for example); it would be a security breach. So what you ask for should not be possible, anyway, there are some techniques to know if the user is logged in or not, but you won't know his id.
For this thechniques you can see:
https://grepular.com/Abusing_HTTP_Status_Codes_to_Expose_Private_Information

Regards